# How to locate file in filesystem using only its name, and not knowing its file extension

Tags: javascript

I have a very interesting problem... I want to be able to have one loop find all images in a directory given ONLY their names, and *the JavaScript code has to figure out their file extensions.*

Take the following code as an example:

```
for(let i = 0;i < 5;i++){
    let toAdd = document.createElement("img");
    toAdd.src = "path/to/directory/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
    gallery.appendChild(toAdd);
}
```

This code should load 5 files from `path/to/directory`, and those five files should be called `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`, `4.jpg`, `5.jpg`.

But now suppose one of those images is `2.png`? Now I get a `404 not found` error, of course...

So what if I want to load files using *exactly* this method, without knowing whether the files will be `.png` or `.jpg`? I want to load them all and render them all according to their proper methods (I obviously don't want to render a `.png` as a `.jpg` and break the page)

---

I treid a `try/catch` block just for the heck of it...

```
for(let i = 0;i < 5;i++){
    let toAdd = document.createElement("img");
    try{
        toAdd.src = "path/to/directory/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
    }catch(err){
        toAdd.src = "path/to/directory/" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    }
    gallery.appendChild(toAdd);
}
```

And that didn't work because 404 errors are not caught by try blocks! (And it's a very primitive solution anyway and scales poorly.)

I wonder if this is even possible or if I'll just have to redesign my page completely so that I don't have this issue.

Comment: From the client side all you can do is try like your doing.  But loading an image is async, you can't catch errors in a try except like this, you need to catch the `onError` event of the image..  A neat solution is make the loading of the image into a Promise, and use async/await, and the try catch will work as you would expect.

Comment: You are going to have to use error handler

Comment: @Keith That's a great idea! I can't believe I didn't even think of using `onerror` !! Thank you very much for the tip. If you want you can write an answer so I can mark it as accepted, since you answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Keith for helping me think of this.

My final working code is:

```
for(let i = 0;i < 7;i++){
    let toAdd = document.createElement("img");
    toAdd.src = "path/to/directory/" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
    toAdd.onerror = function(){
        toAdd.src = "path/to/directory/" + (i + 1) + ".png";
    }
    toAdd.onload = function(){
        // perform actions
    }
    gallery.appendChild(toAdd);
}
```

It still suffers from the same things that my `try/catch` solution suffers from, but at least this one actually works!

It still throws a 404 error, but at least it recovers and loads all the necessary images.